# Change the picture in picture box in C#

Tags: c#, image, picturebox

I am not sure what is my mistake but i am telling you it works before. I want to change the picture in picture box based on the user's choice.

The 1st picture i put is in the picture control box. which i just put the picture without doing the codes. then, when the system received the value that user chose, the picture will change to the 2nd image.

Code:

```
if (fheadValue == 101)
{                            
    Bitmap abc = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile
        ("C:\\Users\\HDAdmin\\Pictures\\humanbody\\MALE123\\images\\malebothandroid_01");
    pictureBox1.Image = abc;
}
```

Before this, i only using this code and it does change to the second picture. but now, its not working. I don't know what is wrong with my code.

then i tried using this code.

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\HDAdmin\\Pictures\\humanbody\\MALE123\\images\\malebothandroid_01");
```

But still, its not working. guys, please help me with this. it does work with the previous project but when i am applying the same method to the new project, it wont work. is there any careless mistake i made without noticing it..??

Comment: are you sure that the path to your pic shouldn't have a file extension? try adding a .jpg or .png to your path. so something like ...images\\malebothandroid_01.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just noticed, you haven't set the file extension of the image. you should add an extension.
whether it's bmp,png,jpg..

**Edit:** Also call pictureBox1.Invalidate()

**Edit2:** As for the comments, there's no need to call Invalidate().

Comment: You shouldn't need to call `Invalidate`, so it is highly likely that it's the image extension that's the cause of the problem.

Comment: thank you guys. im sorry to ask such a silly question. sorry for taking your time.

Comment: @ChrisF Thanks for the highlight, can you explain why it is no nessacary to call the Invalidate function? As I realized the method should be called whenever we need to redraw the picturebox.

Comment: @idish - Well I don't have it in my application which works just fine - though I do call `pictureBox.Focus()` after changing the image so maybe that has the same effect. It certainly not wrong to call `Invalidate`. I should look into why my application works without it just in case there's a bug lurking in there somewhere.